# Having Issues generating SSH Key for macOS to authenticate GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am try to authenticate GitHub via terminal by generating the SSH key and I have followed the steps [on this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-ssh) for macOS, but I keep getting this error

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/el/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Could not create directory '/Users/el/.ssh': No such file or directory
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Saving key "/Users/el/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory
Els-MacBook-Pro:~ el$
```

I have tried all I can but nothing is working. I am unable to clone any repo from GitHub and I cannot must to GitHub as well

Comment: Does your home directory (`/Users/el`) exist? It should, but the error suggests it doesn't. `ssh-keygen` would create the `.ssh` directory *wtihin* your home directory but it won't create your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange, `ssh-keygen` should create `.ssh` directory for you.
In your case, you can create it in your home by yourself (assuming that you have enough permissions to create it) :

`mkdir ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

That will solve your problem.